# How to force a react element to have a children that accepts ref?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using react-bootstrap. According to [their documentation for `<OverlayTrigger>`](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/overlays/#overlay-trigger), the children must be able to accept `ref`.

How can I force TypeScript type check for this?

Here's what I have now:

```js
type OverlayWrapperProps = {
  children: ???? // Something that forces `children` to accept `ref`
}

const OverlayWrapper = ({children}: OverlayWrapperProps) => {
  return <>{children}</>
}
```

---

I tried these but doesn't work:

```js
type OverlayWrapperProps = {
  children: React.ReactElement & {ref: React.Ref<any>}
}

const OverlayWrapper = ({children}: OverlayWrapperProps) => {
  return <>{children}</>
}
```

```js
type OverlayWrapperProps = {
  children: React.ReactElement<{ref: React.Ref<any>}>
}

const OverlayWrapper = ({children}: OverlayWrapperProps) => {
  return <>{children}</>
}
```

This should pass the type check because `<span>` can take `ref`:

```js
<OverlayWrapper>
  <span/>
</OverlayWrapper>
```

This should fail the type check because fragmented element cannot take `ref`.

```js
<OverlayWrapper>
  <></>
</OverlayWrapper>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `children` be some sort of array?

Comment: @j1mbl3s Doing so forces it to have a single child only, which is what I want